# How is it possible to run swagger2markup from .sh script?

Tags: java, sh, swagger, asciidoc

Is there any way to start the asciidoc(or other doctype)-generation 
from .json files using swagger2markup in a .sh-file?

I know it is easily possible ([look there](http://swagger2markup.github.io/swagger2markup-docs/#_maven)) to create a Java class with swagger2markup that 
has this function, but I want to run the programm directly out of the 
.sh - File without creating new artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://swagger2markup.readme.io/docs/cli.
Its a Command line interface (CLI) for Swagger2Markup.